# How do we override the default indexing limit in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I have an AWS Cognito JWT of more than 125 characters for which I need to create indexing in MongoDB. But the problem is MongoDB indexing accepts the character of max limit, 125. How can we set the max limit or is there any way to increase the default character limit.

I tried indexing the JWT(around 150 characters) where I have the following error.

```
  MongoError: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing  1025 { : "abc@xyz.com", "asdfghjkertyjk......"}
```

This how I created schema index.

```
schemaName.index({ email: 1, token: 1 });
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what version of MongoDB server you are using, but the current [Index Key Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) is 1024 bytes. The error message suggests you are trying to index a value of 1025 bytes, so your JWT value appears to be much larger than expected. Indexing large values generally isn't helpful for performance, so I would definitely consider a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a different approach, as indexing a large text/string field is not always the best option.

Use SHA1 or MD5 to generate a unique checksum of the JWT string (which will give you a constant string length) and save that field. Index and search by that field

Another option is to decode the JWT token to JSON and store it as an embedded document - and then you can index the document (but it's risky option IMHO)

Comment: Thank you, Shahar. As per my requirements, I need to use the Cognito JWT token.

Comment: you can still use it - add another field which holds the SHA1/MD5 result - and when you do a lookup - calculate the SHA1/MD5 and lookup by that value.
You'll probably will get a faster index lookup...

Another option is to decode the JWT token to JSON and store it as an embedded document - and then you can index the document (but it's risky option IMHO)